# Can my Android app download its data file from a server which is not of Google?

Tags: android, file

As the title says: our team is new to Google Play, we've finished an app with a large data file (200MB). We're wondering if we can do as follows:

1. Submit the apk to Google (file size < 50MB)
2. Implement a download service inside the apk, linking to the data file hosted on our own server.
3. At first run the app will download the data file from that server.

It would be very appreciated if anyone knowing well Google's policy can let us know.

Comment: I tried Google and stackoverflow but no exact information, so what we need is kind of a confirmation from someone that had done the thing. Your answer was not helpful, but tks anyway..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they fuss, then you can also avoid the Google Play market all together and have users DL it directly from your site and install it.  Of course you miss out on the market exposure and need a way to take money for purchases, but on the plus side you get to keep that 30% for yourself.  We are currently arguing the pros and cons of this amongst ourselves.

Comment: @Tran other negatives: you have to handle updates yourself, come up with your own licensing schemes, language site awareness, user has to setup device so they can install non-market apps,  user trust level is decreased, purchasing friction is increased, if your app ever gets  successful you need good scalability so users don't get bounced. While I also don't much care for the 30% hit there are a lot of downsides to handling all of this yourself. If a franchise like Angry birds is leaving 30% on the table it's not because they don't have the resources to do otherwise ;-)

Comment: Right on all counts Idistic. But the negatives are basically the same as the software retailer via web site/store front. The store keepers in these instances have to work to maintain integrity, like any other, and hoping for a winner like Angry Birds is a loosing gamble for most. My view may be more ideologic, as the monopolies that iTunes and Google Play are creating stifle inoovation by funneling apps through a narrow business model geared to reward those that do the funneling and have ultimate control of what goes out. Oops, soap box.. sorry.

Comment: I don't disagree in principle with what you are saying and share your ideological views ;-) But if your a small franchise this is a huge investment ( creating your own market and doing it right ) before you even know if you will be successful. Personally I would go about it the opposite way (if at all) let Google carry the weight until you have momentum then split off and do your own thing if revenue supported it. I fall into the lean start up camp which above all else applies resources at the proper moment and not until. I also suspect A-birds has negotiated with google on payouts ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can download whatever you like as far as I am know, lots of app's already do this (like apps that have subscriptions, read books, play audio etc)

They do tell you what they think bad content is [Content Policy](http://www.android.com/us/developer-content-policy.html) but they don't much care how you get it (Embedded or Downloadable) as long as you follow a couple of rules which are basically don't surprise the user with huge downloads, let them opt out etc.

Google also just added a new service to allow you to automatically download a expansion pack which can be up to 2GB and can be hosted on their market servers [Google Expansion Packs](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html)

They also have made the down loader and zip compressed access source code available so that you could use it as an example if you want to host offsite data by making some modifications.

Expansion packs have some (in my opinion) quirky requirements and the device must have Google play vs. Google market installed on it, but it's a freebie way of hosting some fairly big data.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the user who wants to download the app from Google Play over Edge, or even 3G. It would be a lengthy download.

What constitutes that big file size? You could strip out the media and put it on your server -- as you say. That'd bring the app down quite a bit.

As for remotely hosting the apk itself, I wouldn't pursue the idea further. Better to fix the apk and keep it in the standard path with Google Play.

The simplest solution would be to do something like this, from within the app, and save the file to the SD card. [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)